# Как определить, файл бинарный или текстовый?

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Дан произвольный файл. Требуется написать программу (C/C++), определяющую, является он текстовым или бинарным. Существует ли такой алгоритм на данный момент?

Какими критериями целесообразно пользоваться?

Comment: по сути все файлы бинарные

Comment: Плюсоваю, вопрос чрезвычайно интересный. Побольше бы таких!

Answer (score 7):

Текстовый файл-это разновидность бинарного файла.Просто разный формат записи данных.Чтоб знать этот формат, нужно знать как этот файл записывался. После записи для считывающей программы он становится безликим набором байт. Однозначного стандарта не придумали. Есть попытки, типа расширений файлов, чтоб указать считывающей программе, как записывались данные. Но эти правила различаются в разных ОС.

Можно попробовать так же, как и определяется кодировка документа - проанализировав контент.

1. В случае с 8-битными кодировками это просто - смотреть наличия непечатных кодов символов.
2. Для UTF-8 и иных композитных кодировок задача становится несколько сложнее.

Comment: Тогда есть два варианта:
1) разделение по расширению (не очень благоприятно, а если нет расширения?)
2) сначала определение кодировки, далее в зависимости от того, однобайтовая или двухбайтовая (по крайней мере первые 127 значений) ?

Comment: Как некоторый `superset` для определенных вами правил - **[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277521/how-to-identify-the-file-content-is-in-ascii-or-binary][1]**

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277521/how-to-identify-the-file-content-is-in-ascii-or-binary

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, очень, кстати, интересную ссылку вы привели. Большое спасибо!

Comment: Ссылка интересная, но все равно спорная. 

Например, следует ли считать файл, содержащий только латинские буквы и символ `'^G'` (`007` bell) двоичным ? И т.п.

Видимо автору надо четко определить, **что именно** он считает текстом.

Answer (score 1):

Благодарю всех откликнувшихся.

В `Linux` есть команда `file`, посредством которой можно решить поставленную задачу.
Есть ли аналог для `Windows`? Пробовал скачивать исходники и компилить, постоянно недостает некоторых заголовочных файлов.

[Fine Free File Command](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/).

Comment: существует несклько портов gnu coreutils на винду

Comment: [GnuWin32 file](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm)

Comment: Их много. Но я вот чего собирался сказать (но почему-то забыл): филе(1) реализует сигнатурный анализ, что как бы весьма далеко от первоначальной формулировки проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Однозначно определить, конечно, невозможно, но в текстовом файле заведомо не будет таких символов, как #0 (нулевое значение байта). С другими непечатными символами сложнее: #13 и #10 -- это символы конца строки и возврата каретки.

Я думаю, что оптимален будет такой алгоритм:

1. Смотреть на нулевой символ.
2. Смотрим на некоторые непечатные символы (но не все!).
3. Смотрим на количество таких символов как пробел и конец строки + возврат каретки, их количество отличается от количества других символов.
4. *Тяжелая артиллерия.* Смотрим на соотношение различных байтов, в достаточно больших бинарных файлов распределение приблизительно ровное, а в текстовых файлах, какие-то буквы будут встречаться чаще остальных.

Если у вас не Юникод, то результаты применения должны быть очень хороши (~95%).

Comment: Представляю себе, как было бы весело, если бы таким алгоритмом пользовались, например, в `svn'e` :)

Comment: Ахах, котик жжешь!

Comment: @Алексей Лобанов, так английский текст в utf-16 это бинарный файл ? 

На самом деле надо просто определиться с **какой целью** проводится деление на текстовый-бинарный.

Comment: @avp смотри последнюю строчку, если кодировка содержит более одного байта на символ, то эта штука не прокатит