# Почему в бинарном файле отображаются буквы вместо чисел?

Tags: c, файлы, hex

Мне необходимо записать элементы массива (целые числа) в один бинарный файл, затем считать оттуда эти элементы, изменить массив и результат (вещественные числа) записать в другой бинарный файл, но вот что-то во второй файл записывается какой-то бред, или не бред. Может кто-то объяснить, что это значит, потому что в интернете ничего толкового не нашел? Осуществил вывод не только в файл, но и на экран, и на экране ответ верный, а вот в файле смущает запись на коде ascii.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, a[10];
    float b[10];
    FILE* f, * f2;
    f = fopen("prob1.dat", "rb+");
    printf("Enter n=");
    scanf("%i", &n);
    fwrite(&n, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("\a(%i)= ", i);
        scanf("%i", &a[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%3i", a[i]);
        fwrite(&a[i], sizeof(int), 1, f);
    }
    fclose(f);
    f = fopen("prob1.dat", "rb");
    f2 = fopen("prob2.dat", "wb+");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fread(&a[i], sizeof(int), 1, f);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        b[i] = a[i];
        if (a[i] > 0)
        {
            if (a[i] % 4 == 0)
            {
                b[i] = 0.1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        fwrite(&b[j], sizeof(float), 1, f2);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        printf("%4.1f ", b[j]);
    }
    fclose(f);
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Бинарный файл представляет из себя последовательность произвольных байтов. Текстовый файл является [частным случаем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/124987/235436) бинарного файла, в котором символы закодированы в виде последовательности байтов с помощью какой-то кодировки.

Всего различных байтов 256: от `00` до `FF` в шестандцатиричной системе счисления. Любые файлы состоят из байтов. И то, какого рода данные находятся в файле, определяется исключительно тем, как мы их интерпретируем. Мы не можем взять произвольный бинарный файл и прочитать его, если не знаем, какова его структура. Потому что байты в файле могут быть текстовыми данными, целыми числами, числами с плавающей точкой или иметь какую-то более сложную структуру.

Поэтому, если мы будем пытаться прочитать бинарный файл как текстовый, скорее всего, некоторые его байты будут соответствовать каким-то символам из таблицы [ASCII](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) (или из какой-то другой таблицы). И это нормально. В частности, байт `CC` соответстует русской букве `Н` из кодироваки [Windows-1251](http://wm-school.ru/html/html_win-1251.html). Суть в том, что не надо читать файл как текстовый, если он не текстовый.

В отличие от [целых чисел](https://server.179.ru/tasks/cpp/total/121.html) бинарное представление [чисел с плавающей точкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/861351/235436) несколько сложнее. Чтобы проверить корректность записанных в файл чисел, можно воспользоваться, например, одним из [сервисов](https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/) для конвертации hex-данных или какой-нибудь программой с требуемым функционалом. Чаще всего на современных системах тип `float` занимает 4 байта.

Итак, можно видеть, что первые 4 байта из вашего файла соответствуют значению `0.1` типа `float`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Следующие 4 байта соответствуют значению `1.0` типа `float`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заметьте, если интерпретировать эти байты по-другому, как другой тип, то получаются совсем другие значения. Но делать это бессмысленно.

Answer (score 2):

> во второй файл записывается какой-то бред

Почему Вы решили, что содержимое этого файла - бред?!

Я написал крохотный конвертер тех трёх значений, которые видны в приведённой распечатке файла:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char  *argv[]) {

union convert {
    unsigned int i;
    float f;
} a;

    a.i = 0x3DCCCCCD;
    printf("%f\n", a.f);

    a.i = 0x3F800000;
    printf("%f\n", a.f);

    a.i = 0x40000000;
    printf("%f\n", a.f);

}
```

И результат работы этой программульки показался мне вполне разумным:

```
$ ./a.out 
0.100000
1.000000
2.000000
```

Не забывайте только, про big-endian и его зеркальное отражение :-)

Comment: я новичок в си, и меня смутили эти символы кода ASCII, т.к. у препода выходили довольно краткие ответы, но кажется теперь я разобрался с этой темой, спасибо